# Is there any way to influence the pokemon in the trozei box?

Tags: pokemon-battle-trozei

The tutorials indicated that when possible I should make use of type advantages and special abilities (Chansey's ability to heal the trozei box's energy). But so far the opportunities to take advantage of these two strategies have been limited.

For example, in the first stage against grass pokemon my trozei box contains only one pokemon (Amaura) that *would* be excellent against grass types, if not for the fact that for the purposes of this game all pokemon only have a single type. And Amaura has been designated as rock, rather than ice. In another stage with Grass types, a potential Ghastly advantage is foiled by being considered ghost rather than poison.

Which leads me to my question; Can the trozei box be influenced by pokemon I have caught, or are they static for each stage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During stage 2, you get the ability to use a "support Pokémon" in any stage - this can be any Pokémon you've captured previously. This support Pokémon will then appear in your Trozei board as an additional Pokémon. This is actually required to encounter the "hidden" Pokémon in many stages (for eg, encountering Vaporeon in one stage requires you to flawlessly capture Eevee with a Water type, which requires you to use a Water-type support)

Further into a the game you will earn extra support slots.